# Link to paid version in Google Play -- how?

Tags: javascript, google-play

I am making a game with separate free and paid versions. (I'm using CocoonJS to convert from the source Javascript to an APK)

I want to create a link from the free version to allow the user to purchase the full game. I want the user's Google Play app store to open to the paid version screen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on Google's manuals:

http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#OpeningDetails